# Tabulate the data after reducing it using frequency count

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
5   3   3   5   10  10  3   8   2   12  8   6   2   5   6   5   10  4   3   5   4   3   3   5   8   3   5   6   6   1   10  3   6   6   5   8   3   4   3   4   4   3   2.5 1   4   2   2   3   5   10  4   4   6   3   2   3   8   3   4   4   3   3   4   8   4   4   2   4   4   3   2   10  6   3   7   3   5   3   1   4   3   4   3   4   4   2   3   2   4   7   4   6   3.5 3.5 5   3   4   3   5   3   1.5 2.5 3   7   2   5   3   4   2   4   5   3   4   5   4.5 4   6   3   2   1   3   2   2   3   4   6   2   4   2   3   6   1.5 3   3   1   4   3   3   2   3   2   2   6   3   15  1   4   5   2   6   2   4   8   2   8   4   4   4   3   8   4   4   8.5 3   2   7   0.5 3   3   3   2   3   2   4   5   6   2   3.5 3   3   2   2   2.5 2   2   5   2   8   2   4   3   3   2   7   2   4   2   4   4   3   2.5 3   3   3   5
```

The function table() return the following values:

```
table(df$var)

0.5   1 1.5   2 2.5   3 3.5   4 4.5   5   6   7   8 8.5  10  12  15 
  1   6   2  35   4  54   3  41   1  19  15   5  10   1   6   1   1
```

What I want to do is to omit all these numbers for which count() is <=6 so that when the table() function run on the data, it will return results that would look like as shown below:

```
2    3    4    5   6   8 
35  54   41   19  15  10
```

What I am trying:

```
test <- as.data.frame(table(df$var))
test[test$Freq > 6,2]
```

And then using it to get the table().
This is really bad work.

Can there be any other shortest method, maybe a one-liner?

Comment: `table(df$var)[table(df$var) > 6]`

Comment: 10 on 10... i also was close to something similar... :) thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are currently doing is perfectly fine. However, if you wanted to shorten the code, you could use `with`to evaluate the new `data.frame` by considering the initial `data.frame`. I would try to avoid running `table` twice as it is redundant.

```
with(data.frame(table(x)), data.frame(x = x[Freq>6], Freq = Freq[Freq>6]))
#  x Freq
#1 2   35
#2 3   54
#3 4   41
#4 5   19
#5 6   15
#6 8   10
```

**DATA**

```
x = c(5, 3, 3, 5, 10, 10, 3, 8, 2, 12, 8, 6, 2, 5, 6, 5, 10, 4, 3, 
5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 8, 3, 5, 6, 6, 1, 10, 3, 6, 6, 5, 8, 3, 4, 3, 
4, 4, 3, 2.5, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 10, 4, 4, 6, 3, 2, 3, 8, 3, 4, 
4, 3, 3, 4, 8, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 10, 6, 3, 7, 3, 5, 3, 1, 
4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 7, 4, 6, 3.5, 3.5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 
5, 3, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 7, 2, 5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4.5, 4, 6, 
3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 3, 6, 1.5, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 
3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 6, 3, 15, 1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 2, 4, 8, 2, 8, 4, 4, 
4, 3, 8, 4, 4, 8.5, 3, 2, 7, 0.5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 
2, 3.5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2.5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 8, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 7, 2, 
4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2.5, 3, 3, 3, 5)
```

Comment: your work is nice, but I just noticed that  
Kristofersen's solution is still better `table(df$var)[table(df$var) > 6]`  would you agree or not?

Comment: @MadhuSareen, In Kristofersen's solution, you are running `table` two times which is not really necessary. It's not a problem for smaller data sets though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good candidate for the `Filter` function too:

```
Filter(function(y) y > 6, table(x))
## x
##  2  3  4  5  6  8 
## 35 54 41 19 15 10
```

("x" is from @d.b's answer.)